# repeat local notification

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I use below code for repeat local notification every week

```
notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
```

How can i repeat Notification every Sunday,Monday ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need two different notifications that appear identical and repeat weekly.